# Normalization in perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, perturbation-theory, normalization

When we have a system with hamiltonian $H = H_{0} + V$, we can expand the ground state wavefunction $\Psi_{0}$ using the wavefunction of the non-interacting system $\phi_{0}$, that is an eigenfunction of $H_{0}$. In the Rayleigh-Schrodinger perturbation theory, we choose the normalization of $\Psi_{0}$ such that $\langle \phi_{0} | \Psi_{0} \rangle = 1$. My question is: How do we know that these wave functions are not orthogonal? In this case, this product would be zero. I read in the book "A Guide to Feynman Diagrams in the Many-Body Problem" that, when the interacting system has a different symmetry from the non-interacting system, we will have necessarily $\langle \Psi_{0} | \phi_{0} \rangle = 0$, but I don't know what means "have a different symmetry", and I also would like a explanation about when we can do this normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s built in the physics of the perturbation approach.  Perturbation theory makes sense when the dominant term to the exact ground state is the unperturbed ground state, else it is not a perturbation.  More to the point, one *expects* that the largest overlap $\vert \langle \Psi_0\vert \phi_k\rangle\vert$ occurs for $k=0$.  if this is NOT the case, it’s no longer a perturbation of the system described by $H_0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "how-to-make-my-QM-textbook-mathematically-rigorous" question. I usually refer these to Kato's [Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/kato1.pdf).
For "reasonable" $H$ and $V$ it can be shown that $H+\lambda V$ has an eigenfunction $\Psi(\lambda)$ that varies smoothly with $\lambda$ for "small" $\lambda$.
Whether $\langle  \Psi(0) \Psi(\lambda) \rangle \ne 0$ for $\lambda \in [0,1]$ depends on properties of $H$ and $V$.